# onActivityResult wont work after onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I created an app with 2 screens: Activity A (main) and Activity B.

When the user clicks on the search button in activity A it opens a ListView named Activity B.

In this ListView the user has CheckBoxes that he clicks and once he clicks Done, the results are returned to Activity A by using onActivityResult.

For some reason, if let say I do the following:

1) clicked the search button in activity A.
2) chose 1 item in Activity B but didn't click done. Instead, I clicked the return button.
3) re-enter again to activity B
4) choose items + click done

Then my app crashes because it says the result is null.

It seems like after I'm clicking on the return button, that the onActivity result is not working between activity A and B.

My code is:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_OK){

                new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        confirmedBooks = (ArrayList<DiscoverBooks>)data.getSerializableExtra("confirmedItems");
                        DateInMillis = data.getLongExtra( "dateInMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    }

                }.start();

            }
            if (resultCode == ChatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
        }
    }
```

and:

```
Btn_Done.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent confirmedData = new Intent();
        confirmedData.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        confirmedData.putExtra( "confirmedItems", (Serializable) itemsSelected );
        confirmedData.putExtra( "dateInMillis",DateInMillis );
        setResult(ChatActivity.RESULT_OK,confirmedData);

        finish();
    }
} );
```

NOTE:

I added the line `confirmedData.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` because I was hoping that it will clear the data from the previous choose however it also seems to work not so well.

If I do these actions without clicking on the return button everything works correctly.

Any reason for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your done button clicklistner code

Comment: ye sorry, added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do please check that you called **activity B** with `startActivityforResult` from **activity A**

And you don't need to set flag on setting result. You need to update it like:

```
Btn_Done.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent confirmedData = new Intent();
        confirmedData.putExtra( "confirmedItems", (Serializable) itemsSelected );
        confirmedData.putExtra( "dateInMillis",DateInMillis );
        setResult(ChatActivity.RESULT_OK,confirmedData);    
        finish();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Yes I call it with                     startActivityForResult(intent,1); and indeed it seems like deleting this line did the job. Bring another bug but solves this one. Thank you